# Is it possible to automatically create a local variable from a method with IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have an object of class RandomClass with a method doStuff() which returns an int.

I'd like to do something like this:

- Type `myObject.doStuff()`
- Do *something* which creates a local variable of the type returned by doStuff() (int in this case)

Right now I do that by first typing `myObject.doStuff()`, use Alt+enter to popup the "Introduce local variable" menu and then use that.

Can I do that faster ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type `myObject.doStuff()` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to immediately create the local variable. You will directly bypass the pop-up and that is really all you gain.

You can simplify the key mapping to reduce the number of keys to press for the `Extract Variable` if it is really necessary.

Comment: Actually that's not bad. I need to get used to it but it's pretty much what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Generally, no, that's the quickest way to do it.

Given that the `doStuff` method already exists, I could do what you described with 6 keypresses in about a second and a half. That's pretty quick, I would think...

On the other hand, if it's boilerplate code that you'll be typing over and over, you could consider making a custom [Live Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) - hit <kbd>ctrl-j</kbd> and type something like `sout` or `psvm` to see some examples...

Good luck!